# XSLT 1.0: Is there a way to get the value of a param based on another param in xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following params defined in my xslt file:

```
<xsl:param name="language">E</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="headerTitle-E">English Title</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="headerTitle-F">French Title</xsl:param>
```

How do I display the appropriate header based on the language param?

This *doesn't* work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('headerTitle','-',$language)" />
```

It outputs "headerTitle-E" as opposed to "English Title" (which is what I want).

I'm trying to find a clean solution for displaying the appropriate text based on the language parameter, without having to use a "choose" block for every bit of text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you now where your parameters are, you can use a single XPath. For instance, try this:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="language">F</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="headerTitle-E">English Title</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="headerTitle-F">French Title</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/
            xsl:param[@name=concat('headerTitle-',$language)]"/>

    </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**However I think that this kind of task should be better accomplished making use of lookup tables than parameters.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:empo="lookup"
    exclude-result-prefixes="empo"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="language">F</xsl:param>
    <empo:header name="headerTitle-E">English Title</empo:header>
    <empo:header name="headerTitle-F">French Title</empo:header>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/
            empo:header[@name=concat('headerTitle-',$language)]"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You might also want use the current header as a variable, just use:

```
<xsl:variable name="Header" select="document('')/*/
    empo:header[@name=concat('headerTitle-',$language)]"/>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide feedback.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was not able to implement your solution because our internal framework prevents calls to document('') for security reasons. The solution that I implemented is to call a server side function from the xsl file that retrieves the text based on a key value pair (in a file language.xml). The function then returns the correct text based on the query string "Language".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the full broadth of XSLT *inside* xsl:param and xsl:variable. So do it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="headerTitle">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$language = 'fr'">
      French
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      English
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$headerTitle" />
```

Actually, the choose block *is* the clean solution, compared to creating dozens of unneeded variables.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. But there is *a lot* of text to translate so I'd rather not have big blocks of code for each label. Is there a way to call a template to set the variable text? I am open to other suggestions too.

Comment: Well, you could use custom, named templates for each, then `<xsl:call-template name="headerTitle"><xsl:with-param name="language" select="'E'"/></xsl:call-template>`. Apart from that, yes, you could use empo's answer.